# Angular material 1.1.1 layout-padding issue with directive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I was implementing a chat earlier with angular 1.6.0 and angular material 1.1.1 and ran into some issues. My goal is to keep the user scrolled to the bottom of the chat when a message is appended to the bottom of the chat only if they were already at the bottom of the chat. I don't want a user to have to scroll down every time a message is added to the DOM.  My auto-scroll was only working some of the time and so I found out that there was extra height unaccounted for.  I figured out the layout-padding attribute was the culprit. It breaks when applied to a directive that contains the template for a message.  When i say break, i mean it adds A LOT of height and almost what seems to be an extra element to the DOM (message.ng-isolate-scope).

Why does this happen?  Is there an explanation? My solution is basically to just remove the layout-padding attribute from my chat container. Check out the following picture and my plunker.

[Message template(directive) with layout-padding has height 87 (INCORRECT, should be 51).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYjau.png)
*Note, the height of the directive is correct if the layout-padding attribute is removed*

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Y2UmFwg2gGaMcHsGVChs?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller("RootCtrl", function($scope, $compile, $timeout) {})
  .directive("message", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {},
      templateUrl: 'message.html',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.message = {
          time: '12:30pm',
          content: 'Same message, but implemented via directive'
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.container .message {
  background-color: #009688;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.container .timestamp {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!-- message.html -->
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <div class="timestamp">{{message.time}}</div>
      <div class="message">
        {{message.content}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- -->



<!-- After looking at the heights for each of the containers w/o layout-padding, uncomment the following and look at the heights again. The message directive looks like its split into two elements: message.ng-isolate-scope and the actual template for the message. Why? -->
<!-- <body ng-controller="RootCtrl" layout-padding> --> 
  <body ng-controller="RootCtrl">
    <br><br><br><br>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <div class="timestamp">
          12:30pm
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          This is my message
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  <!-- This directive has the same template as the container above -->
    <message></message>
  </body>
```

Comment: Did this help you?

Comment: yes :). I tried to indicate the answer was useful but apparently my score isn't high enough.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified, your HTML looks like this when rendered:

```
<body class="layout-padding">
  <div class="container">
    Message 1
  </div>
  <message>
    <div class="container">
      Message 2
    </div>
  </message>
</body>
```

One of the rules in `angular-material.css` is:

```
.layout-padding > * {
  padding: 8px;
}
```

This means that all direct children of an element with the class `layout-padding` will get the specified padding value.

In the example HTML above that is the first element with the `container` class and the `message` element (instead of the second element with the `container` class).

As an invalid HTML element, `message` will be `display: inline` (at least in Chrome, depends on browser implementation) and is why it looks like it does in your image. The blue part of the selection in your image is the height of the default font size (16px in Chrome), while the green is the padding.

A simple solution is to change the `display` value of the `message` element to `block` instead of `inline`. It will then wrap and be the same size as the nested element with the `container` class and the padding will work correctly.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/gFSUWt9H2sLkUzCH8Q7n?p=preview